# Angular 2 and Node.js project structure

Tags: node.js, angular, structure

I am struggling with the project structure for a Node.js and Angular 2 website.
I use:
Nodejs + Express for the server side.
Angular 2 for the client side.

In most guides I found, people put both technologies in the same project. They have a client and server folder but the package.json is in the root. This seems strange to me because your package.json will get confusing because it's mixed with server and client side dependencies.

I was thinking of creating 2 Projects: One for Node.js server-side and one for Angular 2 client-side. But I am not sure if this will work and if this is the correct structure.

Is there a reason that people put everything in one project? Or is it better to create 2 projects?

Comment: 1 - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules 2 - https://github.com/lerna/lerna

Answer (score 1):

I always try to separate as possible. So in my projects i have 2 folders backend and client (But i keep them in same repository).

Using [angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) will help you to build structure of angular project

[Proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) will help you to prevent CORS.

But again it depends, because in some cases when you need server side rendering then maybe it would be better to have all together.

PS But this is my personal thoughts and this works for me pretty well.

Comment: Where do you put the package.json?

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen basically two places one will be for node js second for angular.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen they are totally separated apps / but because of api they kind of dependent